# CloudKit Saving to public and private

Tags: containers, cloudkit, public

I want to save to the private container in the cloud. but with a  conditional i sometimes want to share that to the public database.
Basically i do this:

```
privateDatabase.save(record, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:Error?) -> Void  in
PublicDatabase.save(record, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:Error?) -> Void
```

This takes forever and is saving info twice.

Is there way to save to just one container and have the dashboard relate to both public and private?

Comment: In stead of saving to both, can't i just save to public, and if the user wants to see his own entries i can filter by his surname? I am looking for best practices here and the most efficient way of saving the data.

Comment: Isn't there a limited sharing capability within CloudKit? You can save it to the private and than share it as need be?